# Permutation Test under Non-Symmetry (request for literature)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, inference, causality, permutation-test

In [Firpo (2017)](https://economics.yale.edu/sites/default/files/firpo_possebom_2017_synthetic-control-method-inference-sensitivity-analysis-and-confidence-sets.pdf), a permutation testing procedure is used for causal inference on a treatment applied to one unit (indexed here by 1). As one would expect, the equation

$$p = \frac{1}{J}\sum_{j=1}^JI\{T_j \geq T_1\}$$

is used to compute the p-value of the test for significance of the observed test statistic of the treated unit $T_1$, where $j$ indexes the test statistics of the controls when permuted to treatment and $I$ is an indicator function taking 1 or 0.

This is straightforwards to me. However, in Section 3, he mentions a generalization to the classic permutation test where not all units have the "same probability of being selected for treatment", and gives modified equation for computing the p-value of a test

$$p = \sum_{j=1}^J \pi_j \cdot I\{T_j \geq T_1\}$$

where $\pi_j$ is the probability that unit $j$ will be chosen as the unit receiving treatment.

This sounds reasonable, but I'm struggling to formally make the connection between my understanding of the permutation test, and this alternate version where selection probability comes into play.

In standard randomization theory, we require the null distribution to be invariant under a group of transformations G. For the permutation test, G is the permutation group, and the density function characterizing the vector of responses satisfies exchangeability under the null hypothesis. As far as I've seen, there is no talk of probability of selection here. We simply look at the ordered test statistics given by $T(gX), \ \forall g \in G$ to perform inference.

So, my question is, how can we formally connect this group theoretic understanding of the randomization test with this probabilistic one, where units have some "chance of being selected"? Is there any literature explaining this connection?
Obviously randomization is not always possible in construction of studies, so I'm assuming there's some biostatistics literature out dealing with this directly.

Sorry if this is a silly question. I'm new to this area and don't really even know the vocabulary.